# Docker on Windows: how to do tftp with Linux container?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-network

I have:

- Windows 10
- Docker for Windows with WSL2 integration (using Ubuntu 20.04)

I created a simple tftpd server to run in a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) container and exposed port 69. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        tftpd-hpa \
        nfs-kernel-server && \
    # Clean rootfs
    apt-get clean all && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get purge && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}

# Export the TFTP server port
EXPOSE 69/udp

WORKDIR /

VOLUME ["/var/lib/tftpboot"]
VOLUME ["/nfs"]
VOLUME ["/etc/dhcp"]
VOLUME ["/etc/default"]

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
    # Set correct entrypoint permission
RUN chmod u+x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The script extrypoint.sh just start the tftd-hpa service on start-up and then waits until C+C is pressed:

```
service tftpd-hpa start

echo "Started..."
while true; do sleep 1; done
```

I spin up a container using a Powershell script this:

```
docker run --rm -ti --privileged `
-p 69:69/udp `
-v ${PWD}/tftp:/var/lib/tftpboot `
-v ${PWD}/nfs:/nfs `
-v ${PWD}/etc/exports:/etc/exports `
-v ${PWD}/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server:/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server `
-v ${PWD}/etc/network/interfaces:/etc/network/interfaces `
nfs_tftp_server:latest;
```

As you can see, I am mapping port 69 in the container to 69 on the host. When I do `netstat -an | find "UDP"` in a command window, I do see entries for port 69. This seems to indicate the port is okay. I checked the status of the tftpd-hpa service in the container, and it is running.

I changed the Firewall settings to allow inbound and outbound traffic on port 69. I also updated the firewall to allow the Trivial File Transfer Protocol App (TFTP.EXE) to communicate through it.

The problem is when I try to do tftp:

```
tftp 0.0.0.0 GET test.txt
```

it just hangs and times out. The file does exist.

Why doesn't it work? When I try the same in my Ubuntu Virtual Machine, it works. So this must be related to Docker on Windows.

Comment: After some googling, I found there's a known open issue with WSL2 and UDP packets: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4825. That would explain the problem I am seeing with tftp since it also uses UDP.